# Table column justification when using the p attribute

Tags: tables

I am using the `p` attribute so I can enable text wrapping. How can I get the second column, `Numeric Rating` to be center justified?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.75cm} p{2.75cm} p{2.75cm} p{7cm} }
\toprule
Acceptability &Numeric Rating & General Rating & Improvement Implication\\ \hline
\multirow{3}{2.75cm}{Acceptable and Satisfactory} & 10 & Excellent & No obvious room for improvement \\
 & 9 & Very Good & Minor improvement possible, but not required \\
 & 8 & Good & Some improvement possible, but not required \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{2.75cm}{Acceptable but Unsatisfactory} & 7 & Fair & Limited Improvement requested \\
 & 6 & Somewhat Poor & Significant improvement requested \\
 & 5 & Poor & Major improvement requested \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{2.75cm}{Unacceptable} & 4 & Very Poor & Some improvement mandatory \\
 & 3 & Bad & Significant improvement mandatory \\
 & 2 & Very Bad & Major improvement mandatory \\
 & 1 & Extremely Bad & Extensive improvement or major design changes are mandatory\\ \hline
 & 0 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Can't answer question, e.g., don't remember} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption[General Rating Scale]{General Rating Scale}
\label{tab:genRating}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice that you post a minimal example! I would just like to note that it's not compilable, `\usepackage{booktabs}` is missing.

Comment: @Stefan, whoops forget to copy that over

Comment: thanks for correction! A good minimal example deserves a solution, so I checked it out. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the array package, it provides a shortcut `>` for inserting commands into the column definition, this way you could insert `\centering`:

```
\usepackage{array}
\begin{tabular}{ p{2.75cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2.75cm} p{2.75cm} p{7cm} }
...
```

`\arraybackslash` is a small helper macro which restores the meaning of `\\` as `\tabularnewline` which might otherwise be destroyed by `\centering`.